# Php data(mysql) to excel but fail

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I need to export php data from mysql to excel.

Code:

```
$DB_Server = "????"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "????"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "???";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "????";         //MySQL Database Name  
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
  $azienda = $_POST['users'];
$??= $_POST['pro'];
$??= "SELECT * FROM  ??? WHERE  ??? = '".$variable."' AND 
??? ='".$variable."'";
 $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or 
 die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
 mysql_errno());
 //select database   
  $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select 
   database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
   //execute query 
  $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" 
 . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
  $file_ending = "xls";
   //header info for browser
  header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
 header("Expires: 0");   

   /*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
   //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
   $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
  //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
   for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
  echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
   }
  print("\n");    
  //end of printing column names  
  //start while loop to get data
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
   }
```

That work fine, but excel does not show split columns but all data in a single column, i would like each column of mysql to be an excel column.
It's possible i wrong something?
Oblivius the variable ??? is fake :D

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: too many question marks makes for *"huh?"* what're you wanting to do here; have us fill in the blanks?

Comment: its just variable or db connection, where is the problem?
mysql or mysqli its same... i can change it to mysqli